# How to access custom code generated by Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have created a default *Empty Views Activity* project in Android Studio with Kotlin as language and Kotlin DSL as build configuration language. Then I appended the following code to the app level `build.gradle.kts`.

```kotlin
abstract class CustomTask : DefaultTask() {
    @get:Input
    var generatedCodePath = ""

    @TaskAction
    fun run() {
        val path = File(generatedCodePath).resolve(
            "custom_code/debug/out/com/example/app/CustomCode.kt"
        )
        path.parentFile.mkdirs()
        path.writeText("""
            #package com.example.app
            #
            #public fun customCode() {
            #    println("Hello from custom code!")
            #}
        """.trimMargin("#"))
    }
}

tasks.register<CustomTask>("customTask") {
    generatedCodePath = "$buildDir/generated"
}

tasks.named("preBuild").configure {
    dependsOn("customTask")
}
```

The idea is that the new `CustomTask` will generate a file on each build. After sync & rebuild I have checked that indeed the file `CustomCode.kt` has been correctly generated in `app\build\generated\custom_code\debug\out\com\example\app\CustomCode.kt`.

Now I have tried to import the function `customCode` from the generated file to the `MainActivity` but I have run into unresolved references.

```kotlin
package com.example.gradlegenerate

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.app.* // Unresolved reference: app
import com.example.app.CustomCodeKt // Unresolved reference: app

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Note that the generated file is in package `app` and the activity in `gradlegenerate` so there is no name collision.

I tried to add the generated file in the source sets in app level `build.gradle.kts` and repeat the sync & rebuild & import but no luck.

```kotlin
android {
    sourceSets {
        named("main") {
            java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/debug/out")
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If nothing else, `$buildDir/generated/debug/out` does not seem to match `app\build\generated\custom_code\debug\out\com\example\app\CustomCode.kt`. The latter has `custom_code` between `generated` and `debug`, whereas the former does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right, now it works. Should I delete this question?

Comment: I recommend either deleting it or posting your solution as an answer (I'm not 100% certain what you wound up with, so I cannot readily answer it myself). Regardless, I'm glad to hear it is now working for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the path of the generated code did not match the path added to the source sets.

In `app/build.gradle.kts` I've corrected the source sets.

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    named("main") {
        java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/custom_code/debug/out")
    }
}
```

Note the string `custom_code` that was missing in the question text.

Now I could finally import and use the `customCode` function in the MainActivity.

```kotlin
package com.example.gradlegenerate

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.app.customCode

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        customCode()
    }
}
```

When I build and run the app the output is then registered by Logcat.

```
System.out    com.example.gradlegenerate    I    Hello from custom code!
```